# Configure .htaccess for subdomain

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, cpanel

I have a example.com and i created a subdomain for it in Cpanel. In Cpanel it appears:

**test.domain.com    /public_html/test  not redirected**
I want to access my new subdomain: test.domain.com I have created an index.html in the subdomain folder: /home/domainname/public_html/test

My .htaccess is:

```
 AddType text/x-component .htc
 RewriteEngine on     
 RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off     
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
 RedirectMatch 301 ^/test/(.*)$ http://test.example.com/$1
 RewriteRule ^(en|fr)/([a-z]*) /index.php
 RewriteRule !\.
 (js|ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|css|swf|htm|xml|php|map|ttf|woff|woff2)$ 
  index.php
 RewriteRule ^(form|ajax|captcha)/([a-z]*) /index.php
```

The domain.com have ssl and for subdomain i don`t. I added this line in .htaccess for subdomain:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/test/(.*)$ http://test.example.com/$1
```

But not working: when accessing the test.example.com i get **"This page isn’t working test.example.com redirected you too many times."**

and if using with https:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/test/(.*)$ https://test.example.com/$1
```

I get of course a ssl warning and **Not Found
The requested URL /home/domainname/public_html/index.php was not found on this server.**

What i have done wrong?

Comment: if i comment the htaccess it works the subdomain (it show me the html page) but the domain site not working correct

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should add [`RewriteBase`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase) directive:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
```

You should also update the [`RedirectMatch`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch) directive to:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^test/(.*)$ http://test.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

It tests if the request domain is `example.com`, and if request URI prefix is `test/{any_characters}`, redirect to `test.example.com/{any_characters}` permanently.

Comment: Hi @Ben, if a understood correct the .htaccess should look look like [this](https://plnkr.co/edit/tzH5PcnkT6aZiSmNmFSJ?p=catalogue) . The main domain example.com is working but the subdomain test.example.com not. I am getting an ssl warning (that's not a porblem beacuse i will install an certificate for this subdomain) and then: `Not Found
The requested URL /index.php was not found on this server.
Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.`

Comment: have you set the correct `DocumentRoot` for your subdomain / or correct `VirtualHost` config?

Comment: I didn't modify any config. Just created the subdomain from cpanel. The errror 404 was because it was looking for index.php not .html Now it's working almost fine :) I installed joombla for that subdomain and now i have to deal with the other .htaccess file to work the routing for test.example.com. Thank you so much Ben ;)